# Android Time Picker Dialog Change the Time Shown First

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I used the code below to create time picker dialog. But ı want to edit the time that first facing to user. How can i do that?

```
    private fun show_end_time_picker () {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        end_time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time)
        schedule_end_time_text.setText(end_time)
    }
    TimePickerDialog(
        this.context, timeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(
            Calendar.MINUTE
        ), true
    ).show()
}
```

Comment: you set the time here `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)`, so it should show current time. What time would you like to show instead?

Comment: I tried to change them. they are for to get time users input. I want to change the time first shown to user.like when you open picker, you colud see the time that I selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, the timePicker should start at 22:00

```
    private fun show_end_time_picker () {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = 22
        val minute = 0
        val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
            end_time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time)
            schedule_end_time_text.setText(end_time)
        }
        val tpd = TimePickerDialog(this.context, timeSetListener, hour, minute, true).show()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was tried to make like below code. I guess I  misunderstanded to your comment. cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,,22)

Answer (score 0):

for selecting the device time as default:--

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
timePicker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Or you can do it like this-->

```
TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 13, 0, false); //means 1:00 PM
```